# Number Validation Bug?

Tags: qooxdoo

I try to use the number validation in Qooxdoo but no number is accepted by the validation.
I took the FormValidator Playground Example to make a test:
[Playground example.](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22qx.Class.define(%2522demobrowser.demo.ui.FormValidator%2522%252C%250D%250A%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520extend%2520%253A%2520qx.application.Standalone%252C%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520members%2520%253A%250D%250A%2520%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520main%2520%253A%2520function()%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.base(arguments)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520number%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.TextField()%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.getRoot().add(number%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%252020%252C%2520top%253A%2520100%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520create%2520the%2520form%2520manager%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520manager%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.validation.Manager()%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520manager.add(number%252C%2520qx.util.Validate.number())%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520send%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522Send%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.getRoot().add(send%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%252020%252C%2520top%253A%2520215%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520send.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function()%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520return%2520type%2520can%2520not%2520be%2520used%2520because%2520of%2520async%2520validation%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520manager.validate()%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%252C%2520this)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520add%2520a%2520listener%2520to%2520the%2520form%2520manager%2520for%2520the%2520validation%2520complete%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520manager.addListener(%2522complete%2522%252C%2520function()%2520%257B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(manager.getValid())%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520alert(%2522You%2520can%2520send...%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%2520else%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520alert(manager.getInvalidMessages().join(%2522%255Cn%2522))%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%252C%2520this)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250D%250A%2520%2520%257D%250D%250A%257D)%253B%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D)
Did i something wrong or is it a Bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation function retreived via qx.util.Validate.number expects the validated value to be of type number (int, float), but the qx.ui.form.TextField property value is of type string.

Therefore every input, being null or a string, results in a validation error. 
You have to create your own validation function which first converts the value retreived from the text field into an e.g. integer value (or a float).

Here is an example using the self defined method checkNumber:

[playground example](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22qx.Class.define(%2522demobrowser.demo.ui.FormValidator%2522%252C%250D%250A%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520extend%2520%253A%2520qx.application.Standalone%252C%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520members%2520%253A%250D%250A%2520%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520checkNumber%2520%253A%2520function(value%252C%2520formItem%252C%2520errorMessage)%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520errorMessage%2520%253D%2520errorMessage%2520%257C%257C%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520qx.locale.Manager.tr(%2522%25251%2520is%2520not%2520a%2520number.%2522%252C%2520value)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520ivalue%2520%253D%2520parseInt(value%252C10)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520((typeof%2520ivalue%2520!%253D%253D%2520%2522number%2522%2520%2526%2526%2520(!(ivalue%2520instanceof%2520Number)))%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257C%257C%2520(!(isFinite(ivalue)))%2520%257C%257C%2520value.length%2520!%253D%2520(ivalue%252B%2522%2522).length)%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520throw%2520new%2520qx.core.ValidationError(%2522Validation%2520Error%2522%252C%2520errorMessage)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%252C%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520main%2520%253A%2520function()%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.base(arguments)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520number%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.TextField()%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.getRoot().add(number%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%252020%252C%2520top%253A%2520100%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520create%2520the%2520form%2520manager%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520manager%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.validation.Manager()%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520manager.add(number%252C%2520this.checkNumber)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520send%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522Send%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.getRoot().add(send%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%252020%252C%2520top%253A%2520215%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520send.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function()%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520return%2520type%2520can%2520not%2520be%2520used%2520because%2520of%2520async%2520validation%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520manager.validate()%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%252C%2520this)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520add%2520a%2520listener%2520to%2520the%2520form%2520manager%2520for%2520the%2520validation%2520complete%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520manager.addListener(%2522complete%2522%252C%2520function()%2520%257B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(manager.getValid())%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520alert(%2522You%2520can%2520send...%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%2520else%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520alert(manager.getInvalidMessages().join(%2522%255Cn%2522))%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%252C%2520this)%253B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250D%250A%2520%2520%257D%250D%250A%257D)%253B%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D)

The conclusion is that it is not a bug, but qx.util.Validate.number is not intended to be used in conjunction with qx.ui.form.validation.Manager and form items having a value property of type string.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a bug. Please, use  qx.ui.form.Spinner widget for that, it filters input and doesn't let you enter anything except a digit.

The TextField widget contains string value in spite of you entered a digit.